# How to make a CSS composite scalable

Tags: css

With some effort, I've finally managed to make a composite CSS as seen in this fiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/boywithk9/9L5o0rrf/14/

```css
div.tile-square {
  position: relative;
  background-image: url("http://surfcityapps.com/img/bundle-tiles/background.jpg");
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: contain;
  min-height: 300px;
  min-width: 300px;
  z-index: 1;
}
.tile-square-icon {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 2;
  height: 160px;
  width: 160px;
  margin-left: 70px;
  margin-right: 70px;
  top: 17px;
  display: block !important;
}
div img.tile-square-name {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 3;
  height: 40px;
  top: 215px;
  display: block !important;
}
.tile-square-bundle {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 4;
  height: 15px;
  width: 130px;
  margin-left: 85px;
  margin-right: 85px;
  top: 265px;
  display: block !important;
}
.tile-square-shadow {
  -webkit-filter: drop-shadow(1px 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, .2));
  filter: drop-shadow(1px 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, .2));
}
```

```html
<div style="width: 209px">
  <p>
    <a href="http://surfcityapps.com/our-top-ten-apps-bundle/">
      <div class="tile-square">
        <img class="tile-square-icon tile-square-shadow" src="http://surfcityapps.com/img/bundle-tiles/icon-top10.svg">
        <img class="tile-square-name tile-square-shadow" style="width: 220px; margin-left: 40px; margin-right: 40px;" src="http://surfcityapps.com/img/bundle-tiles/name-top10.svg">
        <img class="tile-square-bundle tile-square-shadow" src="http://surfcityapps.com/img/bundle-tiles/bundle.svg">
        <img class="tile-square-OFFsale" src="http://surfcityapps.com/img/bundle-tiles/badge-onsale.png">
      </div>
    </a>
  </p>
</div>
```

However, I also need to be able to scale it down in size (209px by 209px, and 300px by 300px).

The only way I was able to get the images centered was a method that specifies the sizes of the container and the components.

Now I've realized that seems to make it impossible to scale the whole thing down.

Any suggestions?

Do I have to create a second set of styles/html based on the other width?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, never create an specific CSS styles set for an specific size.

Instead, try always to use **relative** sizes (with percentages).

For example: instead of `width: 150px`, let it be `width: 39%`.

In this way, you'll get that the width will be 39% of its container's width, whatever it is ***(even if the window gets resized)***.

Other good practices that I recommend to you:

- Always prefer a simple solution instead of a complicated one.
- Always put all the CSS styles together within the CSS sheet, and not in the `style` HTML attributes. This way, you will get all the styles stored in just one place, instead of an untidy bunch of declarations along the CSS and the HTML.
- Distinguish wisely the **class selectors** of the **id selectors**: Class selectors should be used to name a set of rules that will be applicable to several elements in the page. One id selector, instead, will be used for just one element.
- Try not to repeat the same style in different selectors. Instead, declare a class and make it common to the necessary elements (I've noticed you already respect this rule. Congratulations).
- Try not to use **absolute positioning**, **`z-index`** nor **`important!`** qualifiers. A good design should not need them (of course, if it is not intrinsically complex).

Based upon these recommendations, I give you my proposal:

HTML:

I've dropped off the `P` element because apparently does nothing, I've added a second `<div>` to prove that the same CSS rules serves for different elements, and I've given a different `id` to each `<div>`.

```
<div id="x1">
        <a href="http://surfcityapps.com/our-top-ten-apps-bundle/">
            <div class="tile-square">
                <img class="tile-square-icon tile-square-shadow" src="http://surfcityapps.com/img/bundle-tiles/icon-top10.svg">
                <img class="tile-square-name tile-square-shadow" src="http://surfcityapps.com/img/bundle-tiles/name-top10.svg">
                <img class="tile-square-bundle tile-square-shadow" src="http://surfcityapps.com/img/bundle-tiles/bundle.svg">
                <img class="tile-square-OFFsale" src="http://surfcityapps.com/img/bundle-tiles/badge-onsale.png">
            </div>
        </a>
</div>
<div id="x2">
        <a href="http://surfcityapps.com/our-top-ten-apps-bundle/">
            <div class="tile-square">
                <img class="tile-square-icon tile-square-shadow" src="http://surfcityapps.com/img/bundle-tiles/icon-top10.svg">
                <img class="tile-square-name tile-square-shadow" src="http://surfcityapps.com/img/bundle-tiles/name-top10.svg">
                <img class="tile-square-bundle tile-square-shadow" src="http://surfcityapps.com/img/bundle-tiles/bundle.svg">
                <img class="tile-square-OFFsale" src="http://surfcityapps.com/img/bundle-tiles/badge-onsale.png">
            </div>
        </a>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
div#x1 {
    width: 20%; 
    height: 20%;
    border: solid 1px;
}

div#x2 {
    width: 53%; 
    height: 53%;
    border: solid 1px;
}

div.tile-square {
    background-image: url("http://surfcityapps.com/img/bundle-tiles/background.jpg");
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}

img.tile-square-shadow {
    -webkit-filter: drop-shadow( 1px 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,.2) );
    filter: drop-shadow( 1px 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,.2) );
}

img.tile-square-icon {
    margin-top: 7%;
    width: 50%;
    margin-left: 25%;
}

img.tile-square-name {
    margin-top: 10%;
    width: 80%;
    margin-left: 10%;
}

img.tile-square-bundle {
    margin-top: 2%;
    margin-bottom: 2%;
    width: 35%;
    margin-left: 32%;
}

img.tile-square-OFFsale {
    position: absolute;
    visibility: hidden;
    z-index: 5;
    width: 60%;
}
```

As you see, I've converted all the absolute dimensions to relative.

*In fact, even the width of example `<div id="x1">` and `<div id="x2">` are set as percentages; you can modify them (or even set a left-margin) to see that the relative aspect keeps the same*.

The class selectors will be shared by the *image* elements, while the `id` selectors are intended for just the container `<div>` elements.

Comment: Wow, you're awesome!!! And thanks for the tips. The reason I had put some css inline with the html is there are different instances that have different length text. I want the type size to be consistent, so it didn't really work to use a style. Also, I have a vertical stack of these tiles, and the <p> element was how I achieved the desired distance between them.  Thanks again!!

Comment: I understand. That's why I recommend you to use IDs selectors instead of inline styles. And you are welcome! :-)